# Scanning character in a while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf

```
char player_select(void){

    char player = 'n';

    while(player == 'n'){
        printf("Select your player (X or O): ");
        scanf("%c\n", &player);

        if(player != 'X' && player != 'O'){
            printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
            player = 'n';
        }
    }

printf("Your character input is: %c\n", player);
exit(0);
return player;
}
```

I am getting some weird output here:

Select your player (X or O): X

Invalid input. Try again.

Select your player (X or O): i

Your character input is: X

Answer (score 3):

Incorrect use of `scanf()`

```
// scanf("%c\n", &player);
scanf(" %c", &player);
```

The `'\n'` in `"%c\n"` does not do what you think.  `'\n'` tells `scanf()` to consume white-space like `'\n'` and `' '` until non-white-space occurs.  You input was *not* as described.

Since `stdin` is buffered, text by itself, will not typically get read until a `'\n'` follows.

It gets complicated to explain in detail why things failed.  So briefly, use `" %c"` instead of `"%c\n"`.  Or better yet, use `fgets()`.

```
buffer player[10];
fgets(ch, sizeof ch, stdin);
if(player[0] != 'X' && player[0] != 'O') { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this will work for you.
I have removed the `\n` inside the `scanf` and i have added `while(getchar()!='\n');` for emptying `stdin`.

```
char player_select(void){

char player = 'n';

while(player == 'n'){
    printf("Select your player (X or O): ");
    scanf("%c", &player);

    if(player != 'X' && player != 'O'){
        printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
        player = 'n';
    }
    while(getchar()!='\n');
}
```

This is the output:

```
Select your player (X or O): A
Invalid input. Try again.
Select your player (X or O): X
Your character input is: X
```

Comment: Suggest `while(getchar()!='\n');` outside the `if()` block to consume the `\n` if user enters a bad _or_ good `char`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    if (scanf("%c\n", &player) == 1 && player != 'X' && player != 'O'){
        printf("Invalid input. Try again.\n");
        player = 'n';
    }
```

Bring `scanf` into the `if`, removing from your above code, and check its return value == `1`.

You can try removing the `\n` from scanf mask if this won't suffice.